# Math.toIntExact inside lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda

I'm learning about lambda expressions. 
Given a list of names, I want to count the numbers of names that start with `N`.

I did that:

```
final static List<String> friends = Arrays.asList("Brian", "Nate", "Neal", "Raju", "Sara", "Scott");

public static int countFriendsStartWithN() {
    return  Math.toIntExact(friends
            .stream()
            .filter(name -> name.startsWith("N"))
            .count());
}
```

The call to the count method returns a primitive `long` but I want an `int`.
I used `Math.toIntExact` to get the `long` value as `int`.

Is it possible to get the `int` value directly inside the lambda expression?

Comment: What do you mean by lambda experssion? That looks alright to me.

Comment: If you know the long value is not too large, you can simply cast it to `int`.

Comment: @Eran and you know it's not too large, because it is necessarily no greater than the number of items in a collection, which is an `int`.

Comment: I just want to know if is possible to do the int conversion inside the stream process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not possible to fit your call to `toIntExact` into your chain of method calls, your *stream pipeline*. This is because `count` is a *terminal operation* and returns a primitive `long` on which no method call is possible. A terminal operation is an operation that ends the stream pipeline and produces a result (or a side effect).

So I believe the best thing you can do is to live with the code you already have. IMHO it’s fine.

Answer (score 5):

Well, here's a somewhat silly way of calculating the count as an int without casting:

```
public static int countFriendsStartWithN() {
    return friends.stream()
                  .filter(name -> name.startsWith("N"))
                  .mapToInt (s -> 1)
                  .sum();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do anything inside the lambda expression you currently have, since that's a Predicate: it returns a boolean. `Math.toIntExact` returns an `int`.

You can do it without the `Math.toIntExact` (or a simple cast) like so:

```
return /* create stream, filter */
    .mapToInt(a -> 1).sum();
```

But this is likely to be slower than doing what you are doing at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another option that is not really better - it is possible to use a collector that applies a finisher:

```
public static int countFriendsStartWithN() {
    return friends.stream()
                .filter(name -> name.startsWith("N"))
                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.counting(), Math::toIntExact));
}
```

This may have an advantage if you need it frequenty - you could build a utility method returning this `Collector` to make it reusable.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do this with `reduce`

```
public static int countFriendsStartWithN2() {
    return friends
            .stream()
            .filter(name -> name.startsWith("N"))
            .map(s -> 1)
            .reduce(0, Integer::sum);
}
```